# Reverse the equation inside of a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to reverse the equation for the dashes.

```
for x in range(1,6):
    for slashes in range(1,(x +1),+5):
        print("X" +("-" * hello), end = '')
        print("X  " + "X" + ("/" * x), end = '')
        print(("-" * x) +("X"))
```

input-

```
xxx XXXXXX X---X X/-X X---X X//--X X---X X///---X X---X X////----X X---X X/////-----X
```

expected output-

```
xxx xxxxxx X---X X/-----X X---X X//----X X---X X///---X X---X X////--X X---X X/////-X
```

Comment: Please provide input and expected output

Comment: Can you add an example? It's easier to understand your question that way.

Comment: This is not the output I get from your code. Also what is `hello` (I assume it's 3)? Also the `for slashes in range(1, x+1, 5)` is a strange construct, because it doesn't work as a for loop when x is smaller than 6.

Comment: I don't understand this question at all. You say the first string is the input, but your loop doesn't use any input parameters except the number `hello` (what is that?).

Comment: @Barmar likewise I couldn't make heads or tails of the question, so I produced a new algorithm to fit (if only because it sounded fun to tinker with)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want what's essentially a "progress bar" delimited by `"X---X"` tokens. Printed by-line you want:

```
xxx
xxxxxx    # I assume this is header?
X---X     # first token
X/-----X  # one slash
X---X
X//----X  # two slashes
X---X
X///---X  # three slashes
X---X
X////--X  # four slashes
X---X
X/////-X  # five slashes ends the output.
```

So each iteration you should have `num_slashes` and `num_dashes`, where `num_dashes` is always a constant `bar_length` less the number of slashes.

```
bar_length = 6
for num_slashes in range(1, 6):  # 1-5
    num_dashes = bar_length - num_slashes
    result = "/" * num_slashes + "-" * num_dashes
    result = "X" + result + "X"
# or:
results = ["X" + "/" * i + "-" * (6-i) + "X" for i in range(1, 6)]
```

however this ignores your header and your tokens, so let's intersperse those.

```
import itertools

header = ["xxx", "xxxxxx"]  # I don't know how you're generating that, so I assume it's static?
tokens = itertools.repeat("X---X")  # infinite sequence of "X---X"
final_result = itertools.chain.from_iterable([header, *zip(tokens, results)])
```

`final_result` is then a list that looks like:

```
['xxx',
 'xxxxxx',
 'X---X',
 'X/-----X',
 'X---X',
 'X//----X',
 'X---X',
 'X///---X',
 'X---X',
 'X////--X',
 'X---X',
 'X/////-X']
```

so to print it as a line like you have above, we'll have to use `' '.join`.

```
print(' '.join(final_result))
```